# Unable to stop Dynatrace Agent with Puppet?

Tags: puppet

I am trying to terminate my dT agent on my servers with puppet but using an `enabled => false` doesn't seem to be working? I would assume instead I will have to kill it by `pid` instead but am uncertain how to do that

Here is what i am using now

```
root@server]> puppet apply -e "service { '/opt/dynatrace-5.6.0/agent/lib64/dtwsagent': enabled => false, }"
Error: Invalid parameter enabled on Service[/opt/dynatrace-5.6.0/agent/lib64/dtwsagent] at line 1 on node server
Error: Invalid parameter enabled on Service[/opt/dynatrace-5.6.0/agent/lib64/dtwsagent] at line 1 on node server
root@server[/tmp]> ps aux |grep dt
root      1406  0.0  0.1 245828 21676 ?        Sl   Nov14  22:04 /opt/dynatrace-5.6.0/agent/lib64/dtwsagent server=localhost
root     12983  0.0  0.0 103312   860 pts/0    S+   12:07   0:00 grep dt
```

I would also assume that i would need to kill this pid prior to removing directories? Here's my entire code block

```
    file { 'remove_dt62':
        ensure  => absent,
        path    => '/opt/dynatrace-6.2',
        recurse => true,
        purge   => true,
        force   => true,
    }

    file { 'remove_dt56':
        ensure  => absent,
        path    => '/opt/dynatrace-5.6.0',
        recurse => true,
        purge   => true,
        force   => true,
    }

    file { 'remove_dt_conf':
        ensure  => absent,
        path    => "${httpd_root}/conf.d/dtload.conf",
        purge   => true,
        force   => true,
    }

    service { '/opt/dynatrace-5.6.0/agent/lib64/dtwsagent':
    ensure      => stopped,
    enable      => false,
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service resource lets Puppet use existing service managers to stop services (eg. initd, upstart, systemd) so you can't stop a service by giving a path like that.

[Like your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34163776/puppet-test-and-remove-an-array-of-files-folders/34176609#34176609), if you have to do it this way, you can remove the service using a `base` provider declaration:

```
  service { 'dynatrace':
    ensure   => stopped,
    provider => 'base',
    stop     => 'kill -TERM $(ps ax | grep \"dtwsagent\"|grep -v grep|awk '{print \$1}')',
    status   => "ps ax | grep "dtwsagent"",
  }
```

As you can see, you can specify the exact commands you want to run to stop the service and check if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at the [Dynatrace Puppet Module](https://github.com/dynaTrace/Dynatrace-Puppet). Its [class dynatrace::role::wsagent_package](https://github.com/dynaTrace/Dynatrace-Puppet/blob/master/manifests/role/wsagent_package.pp) allows for the wsagent to be enabled and disabled.

Answer (score -1):

I dont have an answer for you on your specific question but you will find more dynatrace experts and answers on the [Dynatrace Discussion Forum](https://answers.dynatrace.com/spaces/146/index.html). If I would be you I would repost the question there!

Comment: Not very helpful comment