# Puppet test and remove an array of files/folders

Tags: puppet, dynatrace

I'm looking to make the following code work somehow, it seems if i do not test the files/folders first I end up with the error:

> Error: Failed to apply catalog: Parameter path failed on
>   File[/opt/dynatrace-6.2]: File paths must be fully qualified, not
>   '["/opt/dynatrace-6.2", "/opt/dynatrace-5.6.0",
>   "/opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf.d/dtload.conf",
>   "/opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf.d/01_dtagent.conf"]' at
>   newrelic.pp:35

The pertinent parts

```
$dtdeps = [
  "/opt/dynatrace-6.2",
  "/opt/dynatrace-5.6.0",
  "${httpd_root}/conf.d/dtload.conf",
  "${httpd_root}/conf.d/01_dtagent.conf",
]

exec { "check_presence":
  require => File[$dtdeps],
  command => '/bin/true',
  onlyif => "/usr/bin/test -e $dtdeps",
}

file { $dtdeps:
  require => Exec["check_presence"],
  path    => $dtdeps,
  ensure  => absent,
  recurse => true,
  purge   => true,
  force   => true,
} ## this is line 35 btw

exec { "stop_dt_agent":
  command => "PID=$(ps ax |grep dtwsagent |grep -v grep |awk '{print$1}') ; [ ! -z $PID ] && kill -9 $PID",
  provider => shell,
}

service { "httpd_restart" :
    ensure    => running,
    enable    => true,
    restart   => "/usr/sbin/apachectl configtest && /etc/init.d/httpd reload",
    subscribe => Package["httpd"],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks basically correct, but you went overboard with your `file` resources:

```
file { $dtdeps:
  require => Exec["check_presence"],
  path    => $dtdeps,
  ...
```

This *does* create all the file resources from your array (since you use an array for the resource title) but *each single one of them* will then try to use the same array as the `path` value, which does not make sense.

TL;DR remove the `path` parameter and it should Just Work.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually simplify this down a lot. Puppet only runs the file removal if the files don't exist, so the check_presence exec is not required.

You can't give a path an array, but you can pass the title as an array and then the paths get automatically made.

```
$dtdeps = [
  "/opt/dynatrace-6.2",
  "/opt/dynatrace-5.6.0",
  "${httpd_root}/conf.d/dtload.conf",
  "${httpd_root}/conf.d/01_dtagent.conf",
]

file { $dtdeps:
  ensure  => absent,
  recurse => true,
  purge   => true,
  force   => true,
}

exec { "stop_dt_agent":
  command     => '[ ! -z $PID ] && kill -9 $PID',
  environment => ["PID=\$(ps ax |grep dtwsagent |grep -v grep |awk '{print$1}'))"],
  provider     => shell,
}
```

However, running the stop_dt_agent exec is a bit fragile. You could probably refactor this into a `service` resource instead:

```
  service { 'dynatrace':
    ensure   => stopped,
    provider => 'base',
    stop     => 'kill -TERM $(ps ax | grep \"dtwsagent\"|grep -v grep|awk '{print \$1}')',
    status   => "ps ax | grep "dtwsagent"",
  }
```

Comment: The reason for this is that there was a competing service. Plus 1 for the dt portion